# MySql get duplicate id where other column condition

Tags: mysql, sql

table1:

I need all the item_id records where image_id=1 and the item_id appears in the table more than one time:

So, for the following table (lets call it my_table):

```
item_id     image_id
-------     --------
   1           1
   1           5
   1           6
   2           1
   3           1
   4           1
   6           1
   6           33
   6           34
```

The output for item_id records should be: 1,6

I have tried:

```
    SELECT m_t1.item_id
    FROM my_table m_t1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(item_id)
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY item_id
    HAVING COUNT(item_id)>1) m_t2
    ON m_t2.image_id=1
    WHERE m_t1.item_id=m_t2.item_id
```

Comment: try ON m_t1.item_id = m_t2.item_id WHERE m_t2.image_id = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT item_id FROM my_table 
WHERE image_id = 1 
  AND item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM my_table GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is using `exists`

```
select 
 t1.item_id 
 from my_table t1 
 where t1.image_id = 1 
 and exists( 
   select 1 from my_table t2 
   where t2.item_id = t1.item_id 
   and t2.image_id <> 1 
);
```

Comment: This assumes that `item_id, image_id` combinations are unique, which is probably true, but not explicitly stated by OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from item where item_id in (
   select item_id  from item 
   group by item_id
   having count (item_id ) > 1) 
   and image_id = 1
```